# SQL select from inner join where count greater than

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Doctor

```
doctorid (PK)
doctorname
```

Patient

```
patientid (PK)
patientname
doctorid
```

I have the following query to get the doctors details with the number of patients that he/she consults. assume a patient has only one doctor to consult.

```
select d.doctorid,d.doctorname,count(p.patientid)
from doctor d
inner join patient p
on d.doctorid = p.doctorid
group by p.doctorid
```

Now I need to get the same information but only for the doctors who has more than 1 patients. Please suggest me a query.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`HAVING` clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

```
SELECT d.doctorid,
       d.doctorname,
       COUNT(p.patientid) AS patients
  FROM doctor d
       INNER JOIN patient p
                  ON d.doctorid = p.doctorid
GROUP BY 
       d.doctorid,
       d.doctorname
HAVING patients > 1
```

I used alias (`patients`) instead of `COUNT(p.patientid)`, because `HAVING` clause allows that. But you can stick to the `COUNT(p.patientid)` as well
Also, I suggest you use all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.
And, if you retrieving `doctorname`, you, probably, don't have to retrieve `doctorid`.