# Select value from 2 tables with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select values Employee ID, employee first name, project name from tables `employee` and `project` of the employee assigned to more than one project.

Thanks everybody I can solve them and sorry about this question is not clear

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: SO lacks a proper way to format tables, so I don't see the problem with posting images of tables.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You need to use HAVING. I think this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128236/sql-select-from-inner-join-where-count-greater-than

Comment: @steven SO has full table markup....

Comment: You need to add your desired results for us to understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a JOIN

```
select EmplyoeeID, FirstName, ProjectName 
from EmployeeDetail 
join ProjectDetail on EmplyoeeDetailID = EmployeeID
where (select count(*) from ProjectDetail where EmplyoeeDetailID = EmployeeID) > 1
```

Please read more about joins here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: it's work. but I need to select employees with more than 1 project.

Comment: Oh I overlooked that. Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this (a simple INNER JOIN)

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.firstName, p.ProjectName
FROM Employee e
JOIN ProjectDetail p
ON e.EmployeeID = p.EmployeeDetailID
```

If you want only employees with more than 1 project

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.firstName, p.ProjectName
FROM Employee e
JOIN ProjectDetail p
ON e.EmployeeID = p.EmployeeDetailID
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ProjectDetail p2
    WHERE p2.EmployeeDetailID = p.EmployeeDetailID) > 1
```

Comment: it's work. but I need to select employees with more than 1 project.

Comment: @MongkolwongSonwong please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

A window function is probably the most efficient

```sql
SELECT
  e.EmployeeID,
  e.firstName,
  p.ProjectName
FROM Employee e
JOIN (
    SELECT p.*,
      count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.EmployeeDetailID)
    FROM ProjectDetail p
) p ON e.EmployeeID = p.EmployeeDetailID AND p.count > 1;
```